# Include google api version in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I am developing an html/javascript application and want to build a single file containing both HTML and javascript code.

Is there a way to include google-map api in the same file without using a **script** tag ?

Thanks,

Benoit

Comment: It is a little unclear as to the motivation for this or exactly what you're asking. Are you saying you don't want to load the Google Maps API using a <script src= construct, or just that you want an integrated one page solution, but it's OK to load in the Google Maps API from Google.

Comment: Sorry if i am not clear. 
In my application,I use several javascript libraries (floot, proj4js, the Google Maps API...) I want to add only one script tag in my html page loading a file containing all the javascript API. To create this file, i use a bash script but i did not find out how to include the Google Maps API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - it's called loading asynchronously: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#asynch

Comment: I want to include the google map api in my "application.js" using a Makefile. So my question is where to find the googleApi javascript file.

Comment: That you can't do. You must either statically or dynamically add the script tag to your document.

Comment: OK, is it a licence problem or something like this ?

Comment: The main maps api script is just a stub and it actually inserts more script tags. In addition, it contains code that invalidates it after a certain number of hours.

Comment: Thank you Chad for all this information. You are really skilled on the Google Api topic.
It's the first time I found an APi with such constraints.

Answer (score 0):

We need to add script tag to access google map.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a Google Static Maps API that simply creates imagery. It's non-interactive but works without JavaScript:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: I am looking for the "complete" version